# How to keep and disable the y scrollbar while a popup is displayed with the navigation bar on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

As illustrated by [this](http://codepen.io/silvenon/pen/sglFp) pen, I want to make a popup while retaining access to the navigation bar (that's why I'm not using Bootstrap's Modal). The problem is that I want to keep the scrollbar at all times, but also want to disable scrolling of the background while the popup is active.

I tried a lot of things so far, and pretty much the only one worth mentioning is setting `overflow: hidden` to the body (to remove the scrollbar and prevent scrolling) and forcing the scrollbar on `.popup`, but this doesn't account for the navigation bar, which still jumps.

The only thing I haven't tried yet is including an identical navigation bar in the popup over the original one. But to me that is asking for trouble, is there another way?

If know how to calculate the width of the scrollbar or, more specifically, whether there is a scrollbar or it's hidden (like in OS X), so that won't be a problem. [This](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/10625) technique seems reliable.

I'm aware that similar questions have been answered before, but I didn't manage to find the solution to this specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the navigation bar is positioned over the popup, it hides the scrollbar. The solution is simply to move the navigation bar away from the right edge to account for the scrollbar, by the width measured using the method mentioned in the question.

```
.popup-open .navbar {
  right: 15px;
}
```